# How do I create a variable Select Statement in LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to recreate an Access/SQL like view builder in VB.net

I have two DataTables, AddressListDataTable and MatrixDataTable

These two DataTables will be combined with LINQ and added to a third DataTable called CombinedDataTable

My Issue is that the fields in both the AddressListDataTable and MatrixDataTable will change often, so I need to figure out how to build a custom Select Statement.

Here is my code:

```
Dim both = From row1 In AddressListDatatable.AsEnumerable()
Join row2 In MatrixDatatable.AsEnumerable()
On row1.Field(Of String)("Offercode") Equals row2.Field(Of String("Code")
Select row1("Account") & "|" & row1("First") & "|" & row1("OFFERCODE") & "|" 
& row2("Expiration") & "|" & row2("OfferDescription")
```

This is the line I need help with. I need to be able to create a custom list of field names, because the column names will change each time this is ran:

```
Select row1("Account") & "|" & row1("First") & "|" & row1("OFFERCODE") & "|" 
& row2("Expiration") & "|" & row2("OfferDescription")
```

This code actually works, but it is a manual solution.

So, how do I create a custom select statement each time the code is ran?

Also, here is how I am adding the data to the CombinedDataTable:

```
 For Each r1r2 In both

        Dim words As String() = r1r2.Split(New Char() {"|"c})

        CombinedDataTable.Rows.Add(words)

    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what ended up working for me:

```
Dim addressListColumnNames As New List(Of String)
Dim matrixColumnNames As New List(Of String)

Dim both = From row1 In AddressListDatatable.AsEnumerable()
   Join row2 In MatrixDatatable.AsEnumerable()
   On row1.Field(Of String)("Offercode") Equals row2.Field(Of String("Code")
   Select addressListColumnNames.Select(Function(alcn) 
   row1(alcn)).Concat(matrixColumnNames.Select(Function(mcn) row2(mcn)))

Dim combinedDataTable As New DataTable

For Each result In both
    combineDataTable.Rows.Add(result.ToArray())
Next
```

Answer (score 4):

For this, you can use Dynamic Linq library(System.Linq.Dynamic), Which is available in NuGet Gallery.
In dynamic Linq, you can dynamically generate the select statement.

So after adding the reference, you can change your code to

```
    Dim both = (From row1 In AddressListDatatable.AsEnumerable()
                Join row2 In MatrixDatatable.AsEnumerable()
                On row1.Field(Of String)("Offercode") Equals row2.Field(Of String)("Code") Select row1, row2)


    Dim data = both.Select("new (row1.Account, row1.First, row1.OFFERCODE, row2.Expiration, row2.OfferDescription)")
```

So you can generate the select statements dynamically as a string.

Comment: That may work, however I am getting this error: "No property or field 'Account' exists in type 'DataRow' "

Comment: Here is the correct syntax to the issue I had with your code, Harisyam.  
Code:
    Dim data = both.Select("new (row1[0] as Account))